# How to avoid move_uploaded_file() refresh the page on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xampp

I am using `$.ajax({})` of jQuery, I am trying to move the uploaded file in folder on click. The upload came successful but my problem is when uploading, the page is refreshing I already tried `e.preventDefault()` and `<button type="button">`

This is my html code

```
<input type="file" id="student-img-file" accept="image/*" name="student-img-file">
<button type="button" id="btn-submit-form" class="mt-4">Submit Form</button>
```

This is my jQuery code

```
$('button#btn-submit-form').on('click', function(e){
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('student-img-data', $('#student-img-file').prop('files')[0])
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '../PHPFunctions/AdmissionFormFunction.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result)
        }
    })
})
```

this is my PHP(AdmissionFormFunction.php) code

```
$studentImgData = $_FILES['student-img-data'];

if(move_uploaded_file($studentImgData['tmp_name'], '../FileUploads/' . $studentImgData['name'])){
    echo "YESSSSSSSSSSSS";
}
```

**I am not using form tags by the way**

Comment: Please, show us how you call this code.

Comment: Pretty sure `move_uploaded_file()` does only that: move a file to a different folder. No page reload triggered. Must be something else

Comment: Then there is something wrong in your html or js, the PHP code you show us is not causing a page refresh. As far as I know PHP can never do a page refresh by an ajax call

Comment: Please show us the whole form, not just the inputs.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. I finally figured why is that happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just turned off my vs code live server. I forgot that any changes that i've made in my folder system in vs code will refresh the page.